# C# Dynamic where for a collection

Tags: c#, collections

I want to search a collection based on text box.  The user should be allowed to type in multiple words and in any order.  Meaning if the string in the collection is "What a happy day" and the user types in "day What" the string should appear.  Now I know how to do with with hard coding the number of words allowed (for example only 3 words allowed) with something like this;

```
 nc = oc.Where(X => X.SearchData.IndexOf(words[0]) > -1 || X.SearchData.IndexOf(words[1]) > -1 || X.SearchData.IndexOf(words[2]) > -1);
```

note: yes I know I would have to protect to make sure there was actual 3 values in the array words but that is not shown.

The problem with this is that it limits the user and I don't want to do that.  If the user wants to search off 10 or 20 things then that is fine with me.

Is there a way to dynamically create the Where statement for collection oc?

thanks

Comment: If the user enters multiple words, do the results need to contain ALL of the words or just 1 of the words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more LINQ:

```
oc.Where(x => words.Any(w => x.SearchData.IndexOf(w) > -1))
```

Comment: +1. if data is on any reasonable size converting `words` to `HashSet` first would make searches faster (but no longer one statement :) )...

Comment: This will find partial matches won't it? So if the user types "mat" and the phrase to be searched is "this should not match" it will match. That doesn't sound right..

Comment: In doing some testing I noticed that it does an "OR" command not a "AND" command.  So for example if you have two strings "What a happy day" and "The day is great" then have the user type in "happy great" it returns both.  I would like it to do a "AND" clause.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOf(w)` returns `true` even if `w` is a matched substring. For instance in your example if user enters *Wha* then it gets matched with *What*. As I understand you it is not the case. So you can simply split `SearchData` and search over it:

```
var enteredWords =  SearchData.Split();
return oc.Where(p=> enteredWords.Any(q=>p.Contains(q));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of @Slaks will match on partial words, as per my comment and the answer given by @Alireza

You could try

```
oc.Where(phrase => phrase.Split().Intersect(SearchData.Split()).Count() > 0);
```

There are always various ways with LINQ...